# Meta Stack Overflow doesn't load on any of its pages - questions, users, etc. when logged in

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, site-specific

After going to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions, and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users, none of the pages load.  About 60 seconds after attempting to load the page, it errors out with this page:

[image: An error has occurred while creating an error report. Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

This occurs with both Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10.  Other per-site metas seem to be working.

If I log out, then these sites are loading correctly.

> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.

Is this one of the errors that will be fixed?  If so, what went wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Definitely a server-side problem.

Comment: Same, with the addition of a nice "Server Error in '/' Application." page.

Comment: We're looking into it now. It seems there was [some change today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) that put more stress on SQL Server than it liked. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson The pages appear to be loading correctly now.